# Force page to re-render through popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am new to React. I have a question about how to force the page to render through a popup.

Now I wrote my page in a function component. And it has a popup window that could change the text on the page. However, the update will first go to the backend database and does not show on the page after submitting the popup form.

I know we can use `windows.location.reload` to reload the whole page. But I would like to know how I can re-render the function component instead of reloading the whole page.

Thank you so much!

Edit: This is a part of the code from the main page. `values` and `setValues` are created by `[values, setValues] = useState({name: "", birthDate: ""});`.

```
      <PopUpEdit 
        values={values}
        setValues = {setValues}
        trigger={buttonPopUpEdit} 
        setTrigger={setButtonPopUpEdit}
        >
          Edit
      </PopUpEdit>
```

In the popup form,

```
const onSubmit = async(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    props.setValues(event.target.value);
    props.setTrigger(undefined);
}
```

Both the main page and the popup form are function components.
Thank you!

Comment: you should at least provide some code so we can help you

Comment: Thank you mohamedSdn. I have updated my post with some of my code!

Comment: The description and code sample you have provided doesn't really match up. Your onSubmit doesn't have any call to the backend. Or can you also clarify where and how in the code `the update will first go to the backend database`?

Comment: @BikramKarki Ohh, I skipped the code of that part. There is an api-hook call in the onSubmit. But I think that one should not matter on the re-render？

Answer (score 0):

in react js everything is based on `state`. you should add `useState` hook which is rendered with each change.

See also [Basic Hook useState](https://rea)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My problem is that I want my main page to re-render after the popup form submit. There is a button on my main page, which will generate a popup form. I have passed a useState hook to the pop-up form component (in a separate .js file). And I will update the hook in that file based on the input using props.setState. But when I submit the form. The main page does not re-render.